# error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 2022

Tags: android

I'm creating a mobile game for android and I have a problem when after build and when test game get crashing and stop app

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Bug Screenshot

[image: 1]

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.game/com.my.game.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:256)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:167)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1027)
    at org.apache.cordova.ConfigXmlParser.setStartUrl(ConfigXmlParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.cordova.ConfigXmlParser.getLaunchUrl(ConfigXmlParser.java:53)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadConfig(CordovaActivity.java:169)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onCreate(CordovaActivity.java:107)
    at com.my.game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

'MainActivity' Code :

```
    package com.my.game;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10017" android:versionName="1.0.1.7" package="com.my.game" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.my.game" version="1.0.0.6" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>game</name>
    <description>ads</description>
    <author>game</author>

    <icon density="xxxhdpi" height="256" src="www/icon-256.png" width="256" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" height="128" src="www/icon-128.png" width="128" />


        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />


  <platform name="android">


    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="10.0" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />


    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />

        <preference name="ShowTitle" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />



    <plugin name="cordova-admob-sdk" spec="~0.22.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="~0.25.0">
        <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="0000000000000000~0000000000" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" />
    <plugin name="com-artemisoftnian-plugins-unityads2" />

  </platform>


</widget>
```

and i use these plugins in project :

com-artemisoftnian-plugins-unityads2
cordova-admob-sdk

cordova-custom-config

cordova-plugin-admob-free

cordova-plugin-file

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

cordova-plugin-statusbar

cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

I was added recently com-artemisoftnian-plugins-unityads2 plugin

i don't Very Good in Android Studio so Please i just need sample answer
Thanks for everyone will help

Comment: It's crashing parsing your Cordova configuration.  The problem is likely there.

Comment: I Edit Question and add config.xml code you can take a look